# Issue with mouse events firing instantly on page load and never again

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a flyout menu that uses jquery animate when you hover to show itself then it collapses when you mouse out.  I initially started with hoverIntent and the following code:

```
function collapseMenu() {
    $("#myMenu").animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow");
}

function expandMenu() {
    $("#myMenu").animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow");
}

$('#myMenu').hover(expandMenu(), collapseMenu());
```

When I load the page the menu moves right 50 pixels then left 50 pixels.  And then when I actually do hover over the menu I get the following console error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

on lines 69 and 82 of hoverintent.js

So I just tried jquery's .hover and got the same results, without the error.  After that, I digressed to the following test:

```
$('#myMenu').mouseenter(alert("mouse entered menu"));
$('#myMenu').mouseleave(alert("mouse left menu"));
```

Now on page load I get two alerts immediately... nothing on hover.  I've tried these mouseenter and mouseleave events in the document.ready and outside of it (just for fun), both have the same results.  If you're curious, here's my html for the menu

```
    <ul id="myMenu" class="nav nav-list">
        <li id="lnkHome" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Issue Reports</li>
        <li id="lnkSoftware" ><a href="#">Software and Apps</a></li>
        <li id="lnkOS" class="disabled"><a href="#">Operating Systems</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: what is the code at `on lines 69 and 82 of hoverintent.js` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code

```
$('#myMenu').hover(expandMenu, collapseMenu);
```

`$('#myMenu').hover(expandMenu(), collapseMenu());` actually executes the functions instantly and assigns their return value as the hover/out event handlers